# New Dataframe column based on regex match of at least one of the element in each row

Tags: python, pandas

How would you implement the following using pandas?

**part 1:** 
I want to create a new conditional column in input_dataframe. Each row in input_dataframe will be matched against a regex. If at lease one element in the row matches, than the element for this row in the new column will contain the matched value(s).

**part 2: A more complete version would be:**
The source of the regex is the value of each element originating form another series. (i.e. I want to know if each row in input_dataframe contains a value(s) form the passed series.

**part 3: An even more complete version would be:**
Instead of passing a series, I'd pass another Dataframe, regex_dataframe. For each column in it, I would implement the same process as part 2 above. (Thus, The result would be a new column in the input_dataframe  for each column in the regex_dataframe.)

**example input:**

```
input_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':['hose','dog','baby'],
    'b':['banana','avocado','mango'],
    'c':['horse','dog','cat'],
    'd':['chease','cucumber','orange']
})
```

**example regex_dataframe:**

```
regex_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    'e':['ho','ddddd','ccccccc'],
    'f':['wwwwww','ado','kkkkkkkk'],
    'g':['fffff','mmmmmmm','cat'],
    'i':['heas','ber','aaaaaaaa']
})
```

**example result:**

```
 result_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': ['hose', 'dog', 'baby'],
        'b': ['banana', 'avocado', 'mango'],
        'c': ['horse', 'dog', 'cat'],
        'd': ['chease', 'cucumber', 'orange'],

        'e': ['ho', '', ''],
        'f': ['', 'ado', ''],
        'g': ['', '', 'cat'],
        'i': ['heas', 'ber', '']
    })
```

Rendered:[image]

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output to this question

Comment: read [mcve] and [edit] your post accordingly.  This feels more like you asking us to complete a task for you and less like "Hey fellow programmers, I've run into a problem..."

Comment: Updated, hope it's better now.
I'm not sure how to approach the solution so I'm not posting potential solution code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, rename `regex_dataframe` so individual cells correspond to each other in both dataframes.

```py
input_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':['hose','dog','baby'],
    'b':['banana','avocado','mango'],
    'c':['horse','dog','cat'],
    'd':['chease','cucumber','orange']
})

regex_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':['ho','ddddd','ccccccc'],
    'b':['wwwwww','ado','kkkkkkkk'],
    'c':['fffff','mmmmmmm','cat'],
    'd':['heas','ber','aaaaaaaa']
})
```

1. Apply the method `DataFrame.combine(other, func, fill_value=None, overwrite=True)` to to get pairs of corresponding columns (which are Series).
2. Apply `Series.combine(other, func, fill_value=nan)` to get pairs of corresponding cells.
3. Apply regex to the cells.

```py
import re

def process_cell(text, reg):
    res = re.search(reg, text)
    return res.group() if res else ''

def process_column(col_t, col_r):
    return col_t.combine(col_r, lambda text, reg: process_cell(text, reg))

input_df.combine(regex_dataframe, lambda col_t, col_r: process_column(col_t, col_r))
```